# SQL Server FUNCTION overflow int vs bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server function which returns a `bigInt` and using this in a trigger to assign a value to a column of type `bigint`. However when I run the trigger, an overflow exception occurs (`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`), i.e. it treats it as an `int`, not a `bigint`

The function is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[longIntDateTime] ()
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar bigint;
    DECLARE @now Datetime;

    set @now = getdate();
    SET @ResultVar=DATEPART(YYYY,@now)*100000000 + DATEPART(MM,@now)*1000000 + DATEPART(DD,@now)*10000 + DATEPART(HH,@now)*100;
    --  DATEPART(HH,@now)*100 +  DATEPART(MI,@now);

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN (@ResultVar);
END
```

The trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[employeesInsert] 
ON  [dbo].[employees] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    UPDATE employees
    SET changeTimeStamp = dbo.longIntDateTime()
    FROM inserted INNER JOIN employees On inserted._id = employees._id  
END
```

and the table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employees](
    [_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [employee_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [isActive] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isDeleted] [int] NOT NULL,
    [changeTimeStamp] [bigint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([_id] ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_employees_isActive]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [isActive]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_employees_isDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [isDeleted]
GO
```

If I take two '0's off the first yyyy part of the function, the trigger succeeds, however as is, it fails.

Clearly the value produced is less than a big int.

any ideas?

anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
SET @ResultVar=DATEPART(YYYY,@now)*100000000 + DATEPART(MM,@now)*1000000 + DATEPART(DD,@now)*10000 + DATEPART(HH,@now)*100;
```

The constants are interpreted as `int` so the entire calculate is done that way.  You can fix this easily by casting the first to `bigint`:

```
SET @ResultVar=DATEPART(YYYY,@now)*cast(100000000 as bigint)+ DATEPART(MM,@now)*1000000 + DATEPART(DD,@now)*10000 + DATEPART(HH,@now)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because DATEPART returns int.Try to cast to bigint before multiplying

```
cast (DATEPART(YYYY,@now) as bigint)*100000000
```